# Reading File Details into an Array before Quicksorting

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am currently working on a swimmer's database system, using text files to store the data and the ASA number as a primary key. I want to read these details into an array so that I can then quicksort them more easily. However, I am stuck on both the array and the quicksort, and am not sure how to proceed. Below is the code I have got so far.

For the array:

```
Sub ReadSwimmerFile()
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Swimmer() As aSwimmer

    'Finds the number of records in 'swimmers.txt'
    Dim SwimmerFile As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Swimmers.txt")
    Dim Last As Integer = Len(SwimmerFile)

    'reads out records in 'Swimmer.txt' into an array
    FileOpen(1, "Swimmer.txt", OpenMode.Input)
    While Not EOF(1)
        For Count = 0 To Last
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).ASANo)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Surname)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Name)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).DoB)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Gender)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).MembType)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Squad)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Address1)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Address2)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Address3)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Town)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).County)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Postcode)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).HomeNo)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).MobileNo)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).Email)
            Input(1, Swimmer(Count).DateJoint)
        Next
    End While
    FileClose(1)

End Sub
```

For the quicksort:

```
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    If First < Last Then
        J = First
        K = Last + 1
        Do
            Do
                J = J + 1
            Loop Until ASANo(J) >= ASANo(First) Or J = Last

            Do
                K = K - 1
            Loop Until ASANo(K) <= ASANo(First)

            If J < K Then
                Call Swap(ASANo(J), ASANo(K))
            End If

        Loop Until J >= K

        Call Swap(ASANo(First), ASANo(K))
        Call QuickSort(First, K - 1, ASANo)
        Call QuickSort(K + 1, Last, ASANo)
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone show me where to go from here or even if my code is inefficient and suggest a different way to go about solving this problem please?

Comment: There are **much** better ways tor read files in NET than those legacy File operations; And much better ways to store data than flat flies - serializing for instance.  To sort and array, just use `Array.Sort(myArray)` ... but there are also much better collections available in NET than arrays

Comment: @plutonix how would I go about serializing my files? And what would you suggest I do instead of using an array?

Comment: you need to edit your question for whatever answers you really want